# How can I quickly convert from hexadecimal to decimal in Scratch?

Tags: hex, decimal, mit-scratch

In other languages you can use things like `0xFF` = `255`. I am working on a decoding project and I would like to be able to quickly convert from hexadecimal to decimal.

I was wondering if there was a very quick way to do this, besides writing a [hexadecimal convertor](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/71161350/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out you can! It's fairly simple. Essentially all you have to do is this:

`((join "0x" "<number>") + 0)`
[See it in Scratchblocks!](http://bit.ly/1VJrILi)

You will, however, have to manually create a program to convert from decimal to hexadecimal.

Comment: Haha, cool.

I come here and remember, oh, yes, I need to accept my answer! Except I still have to wait an hour lol. :P